# Proving that ring multiplication in modules form homomorphism and $(\alpha-\beta)x = \alpha(x)-\beta(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

My book has the following question:

> Prove that, for any given element $x$ of an arbitrary module $X$ over
>   $R$, the assignment $\alpha \to \alpha x$ defines a homomorphism
>
> $$h_a: R \to X$$
>
> of the **additive group $R$** into the additive group $X$. Hence,
>
> $$0x = 0, (\alpha-\beta)x = \alpha x -\beta x, n(\alpha x) = (n\alpha)
>  x$$
>
> hold for all elements $\alpha, \beta\in R$ and every integer $n$. By
>   means of these, show that $px=0$ holds for all $x\in X$ if $R$ is of
>   characteristic $p$.

Well, since for a module $X$ we must have

$$\alpha(x+y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$$

for all $x,y\in X$

which proves that $h_a(x+y) = h_a(x) + h_a(y)$. But what exactly is the additive group or $R$? Did I do it right?

Since it's an homomorphism, we know that $h_a(0) = 0$, hence $0x = 0$,
but what about $(\alpha-\beta)x = \alpha x -\beta x$ and  $n(\alpha x) = (n\alpha) x$?

Comment: Are you asking why $h_{a}$ is a group homomorphism? That's quite obvious by the definition of $h_{a}$: Since $R$ is a ring, it is also an additive group. Since $X$ is an $R$-module, we have that $h_{a}(\alpha + \beta)=(\alpha + \beta)x$ (here $x$ is a fixed element in $X$), so we get an additive group homomorphism.  Also  you can get the things your book asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ring $R$ has two operations defined on its elements, addition ($+$) and multiplication ($\cdot$) with the property that $R$ is an abelian group under addition. Additive group of $R$ refers to this group under addition. Multiplication between elements of $R$ is ignored while considering $R$ as an additive group.

I prefer to denote the map $R\rightarrow X$ defined as $\alpha\mapsto \alpha x$ for given $x\in X$, by $h_x$ instead of $h_a$ (thinking of $h_x$ as a $``$multiplication by $x"$ map). This map is a homomorphism between the additive group of $R$ and $R$-module $X$ (again considered as an additive group) because $$h_x(\alpha+\beta)=(\alpha+\beta)x=\alpha x+\beta x=h_x(\alpha)+h_x(\beta).$$ Now as you noted, $h_x(0)=0\Rightarrow 0x=0$, and $$h_x(\alpha-\beta)=h_x(\alpha)-h_x(\beta)\Rightarrow (\alpha-\beta)x=\alpha x-\beta x,$$ $$h_x(n\alpha)=nh_x(\alpha)\Rightarrow (n\alpha)x=n(\alpha x).$$